# Is it possible to launch a DialogFragment from a Preference in a PreferenceActivity?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I am converting my app to use the v4 compatibility package and fragments. I have done well so far, but I need to launch a DialogFragment from a preference click in a `PreferenceActivity`. Since there isn't a PreferenceFragment in the compatibility library, I'm stuck with using `PreferenceActivity`. Is it possible to get a reference to the fragment manager and call the `DialogFragment` or do I just have to continue using the old dialog if I need a dialog from a preference?

Comment: Can I ask how you are launching the preferenceActivity from inside a fragment? Or is your main activity an Activity?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not without jumping through hoops.

You could make a very simple activity with the sole purpose of launching the DialogFragment. If you do this you will need to finish() that activity when the DialogFragment dialog has been dismissed.

Comment: Thanks. I will give you credit for the answer. There is no way to do it without some major hacking like you said. I just stuck to using standard dialogs with the preference activities so I have a couple redundant dialogs for now.

Comment: That is the best bet unless you are using the same Dialog somewhere else. Even with the sacrificial activity I couldn't find a good way to determine when the Dialog was dismissed from outside the DialogFragment which led to more hacks.